# Deadlock sometimes occur when using select.select in both parent and child processes

Tags: python, websocket, io, subprocess, pipe

Hi I have a question which bothered me for 2 weeks. I have tried to solve it but now still encounter deadlock issue sometimes. My detailed question is as follows and thanks for your kind help.

There are one parent process and three child processes. The parent process is used to chain three command-line programs which can be regarded as preprocessing step, main processing and post-processing step.

```py
# Parent process

pre_process = subprocess.Popen("python pre1.py | python pre2.py | python pre3.py", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
main_process = subprocess.Popen("python main.py", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
post_process = subprocess.Popen("python post1.py | python post2.py", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

while True:
    read_stdouts, _, _ = select.select([pre_process.stdout, main_process.stdout, post_process.stdout], [], [], 0)

    for read_stdout in read_stdouts:
        if read_stdout == pre_process.stdout:
            # Do something
            print(output1, file=main_process.stdin)
        elif read_stdout == main_process:
            # Do something
            print(output2, file=post_process.stdin)
        else:
            # Do something and write to socket
```

In the parent process, I used subprocess.Popen in Python to create three subprocesses and set stdin/stdout to PIPE. select.select was used to monitor and forward messages from one step to the next step.

In the main processing child process, I also used select.select to monitor the incoming message. A time window is set to collect messages in a fixed period of time and process them together in one time to improve efficiency.

```py
# Main processing child process

while True:
    inputs = []
    while True:
        if select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 0)[0]:
            line = sys.stdin.readline()
            inputs.append(line.strip())
        else:
            break

    if len(inputs) < 1:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        continue

    # Time-consuming procedure to process the list inputs
```

At first, I set the timeout parameters of select.select in both parent and child processes as 0, making it nonblocking. However, the entire program will be deadlock quite often. Then I tried to carefully tune the 2 timeouts to make them nonzeros. This will decrease the frequency I encounter deadlock, but it is still there.

When I encounter the deadlock, I just need to press enter to give a new input to the program to make the program continue.

I really appreciate it if you can give me some clue of this issue. Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Can you make this a [mcve] by posting your code?

Comment: @SuperStormer Thanks for your kind help! I have added some code for your reference:)